# How to get the lines of code committed by a user to git-hub using java code?

Tags: java, git, github

Any service API is available in git-hub to get the user profile of the git user.
Eg: Using my JAVA application, I want to know the total lines of code committed by a user who is logged in to git using my JAVA application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that GitHub provides a way to track total lines of code committed.  In general, it's not a very interesting metric and it's hard to pin down.  Should it include all lines added?  Should it include lines removed?  What about code that has been totally reverted by other code?  What about files that are binary that don't have useful line breaks?

GitHub does have activity events that you can query via the API, but I don't think this is one of them.  Perhaps if you tell us more about the goal you want to achieve with finding this information, we can tell you a good way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Dear @bk2204
Thanks for responding.
In my java application, I have to analyse the productivity of a git user, who is logged in to gitHub through my application.

I have referred Jgit, but unfortunately, it will not give the user profile (like lines of code, total repository..etc)

Comment: If you want to do this, you'll need to do it with a copy of the repository, although I recommend against using this as a metric to judge developer productivity.  Sometimes spending several days just to write three lines of code fixing a serious bug is more valuable than writing thousands of lines of other code.

Comment: you are absolutely right. This is for our training purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a post or get, after you only need to filter the information

```
package com.co.request.get;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GetRequest {

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    public String doRequest(String url) throws IOException {
        httpClient= HttpClients.createDefault();
        StringBuilder dto=new StringBuilder();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        // add request headers
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "UTF-8");

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {

            // Get HttpResponse Status
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Header headers = entity.getContentType();

            System.out.println(headers);

            if (entity != null) {
                // return it as a String
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                dto.append(result);
            }

        }
        return dto.toString();
    }

    public void closeClient() throws IOException {
        this.httpClient.close();
    }
}
```

© 2020 GitHub, Inc.

This link permits to do a post or get

[post or get with java](https://github.com/wilson1234567891962/Request-post-or-get-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the exact solution for my requirement.

Git provides the below API to capture the details about the particular commit.
https://api.github.com/repos/{{gitUserName}}/{{repoName}}/commits/{{commitID}}

The above call gives details like:

- commit date,
- commit message
- total no of lines added
- total no of lines deleted
- total lines of change
  .etc